# How to convert a variable to a string on Powershell?

Tags: powershell, type-conversion

I would like to convert accessPolicyExpiryTime to a string so i can truncate the output with Replace().

```
$accessPolicyExpiryTime=Get-AzStorageContainerStoredAccessPolicy -Context $ctx
```

Do you know how to that ?
Thank you all

```
$accessPolicyExpiryTime.Replace(@{ExpiryTime=)
```

error is : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: That error implies that your $accessPolicyExpiryTime variable is null, which means you aren't getting a value from Get-AzStorageContainerStoredAccessPolicy.

Comment: well before you can convert it to string you need to make sure its not null. From your error, the `$accessPolicyExpiryTime` variable is null.

Comment: Perhaps you just want the raw expiry time value instead of the whole object? `$accessPolicyExpiryTime = (Get-AzStorageContainerStoredAccessPolicy -Context $ctx).SharedAccessExpiryTime`